# WP7 Toolkit PerformanceProgresBar and UI thread (losing dots effect)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, binding, toolkit

I have a very hard time managing the ProgressBar from WP Toolkit.
In my project I have a listbox populated with databound items. 
The population process goes like this:

1. show progress bar (visibility changed to visible, IsIndeterminate to true),
2. make a rest request,
3. get a response,
4. parse a collection of items,
5. bind items in memory to list,
6. hide progress bar (visibility to collapsed, IsIndeterminate to false).

My problem now is:
The Indeterminate flag seems to change too fast (different threads i think?). This causes the progress bar to display sometimes only one rectangle. 
How can I ensure that the progress bar will dissapear only after databinding and listbox refreshing is complete?

Here is my response callback:

```
private void DataLoaded(object o, RestResponseEventArgs e)
{   
  int i = 0;
  List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>();
  foreach (JObject current in e.JsonObject["entries"].Children())
  {
     Entry e = Entry.Parse(current);
     entries.Add(e);
  }
  this.MyListBox.ItemsSource = entries;
  this.ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
  this.ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() method :

```
    private void DataLoaded(object o, RestResponseEventArgs e)
    { 
      Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
      {
       int i = 0;
       List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>();
       foreach (JObject current in e.JsonObject["entries"].Children())
       {
         Entry e = Entry.Parse(current);
         entries.Add(e);
       }
       this.MyListBox.ItemsSource = entries;
       this.ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

   this.ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
  });    
}
```

Comment: first provide name to ProgressBar in xaml and use that name when you want to disappear that progressbar

Comment: ProgressBar is the name of Toolkit's PerformanceProgressBar, I named it this way only to simplify the example code. I don't think it's a trivial problem. Actually I suspect that maybe some of my custom controls are crippling the apps performance.